# Color of alternate rows in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, migration

I am working with C# environment and I have the below code that I tested and it works under Visual Basic .Net:

```
Private Sub GridView1_RowCreated(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowDataBound  
    if e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow then

        Dim RowNum as Integer
        RowNum = e.Row.RowIndex

        if RowNum mod 2 = 1 then
            e.Row.Attributes.Add("onmouseout", "this.style.backgroundColor='#DDDDDD'")
        else
            e.Row.Attributes.Add("onmouseout", "this.style.backgroundColor='#FFFFFF'")
        end if

        e.Row.Attributes.Add("onmouseover", "this.style.backgroundColor='DeepSkyBlue'")
        e.Row.Attributes("onclick") = Me.Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(Me.GridView1, "Select$" & e.Row.RowIndex) 
    End If
End Sub
```

So, I try to convert it to C# language and couldn't get it to work.

1. There is no "handles" option in C#
2. Somehow, "`e.Row.Attributes("onclick")`" works in VB, but not in C#

   ```
   private void GridView1_RowCreated(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs e)
   {
       if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
       {
           int RowNum = e.Row.RowIndex;
           if (RowNum % 2 == 1)
           {
               e.Row.Attributes.Add("onmouseout", "this.style.backgroundColor='#DDDDDD'");
           }
           else
           {
               e.Row.Attributes.Add("onmouseout", "this.style.backgroundColor='#FFFFFF'");
           }

           e.Row.Attributes.Add("onmouseover", "this.style.backgroundColor='DeepSkyBlue'");
           e.Row.Attributes("onclick") = this.Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(this.GridView1, "Select$" & e.Row.RowIndex);
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change it to this:

```
e.Row.Attributes["onclick"] = this.Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(this.GridView1, "Select$" + e.Row.RowIndex);
```

in C# arrays are called with brackets not parantheses. Also, we use plus signs instead of ampersands to concatenate strings.

You could also do this (to match the code directly above it):

```
e.Row.Attributes.add("onclick", this.Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(this.GridView1, "Select$" + e.Row.RowIndex));
```

Comment: Thanks Lawrence, any advise to perform a same "Handles" option in VB?

Comment: Is that a separate question? I don't see how it's related to the original question. If this solves your problem, check this one as solved and create a separate thread for your other question.

Comment: Click the checkbox to the left of the answer.